# How do I specify multiple values in SQL query where clause?

Tags: sql, where-clause

My current query is:

```
Select Distinct
  SomeDay.SomeDayID, SomeDay.FolderName, SomeDay.FolderColor
from
  SomeDay, SomeDayEvent
where
  SomeDay.SomeDayID != 4,3,2,1;
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question.

Answer (score 8):

I think you want:

```
Select Distinct
  SomeDay.SomeDayID, SomeDay.FolderName, SomeDay.FolderColor
from
  SomeDay, SomeDayEvent
where
  SomeDay.SomeDayID not in (4,3,2,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem based only.

```
Select Distinct
SomeDay.SomeDayID, SomeDay.FolderName, SomeDay.FolderColor
from 
SomeDay, SomeDayEvent 
where
SomeDay.SomeDayID>4;
```

Comment: I quite like the answer but while that works for this particular instance of this particular problem what happens when he doesn't want id 5?

Answer (score -1):

That should be something like

```
Select Distinct
   SomeDay.SomeDayID, SomeDay.FolderName, SomeDay.FolderColor
from  
   SomeDay, SomeDayEvent
where
   SomeDay.SomeDayID != 4
and
   SomeDay.SomeDayID != 3
and
   SomeDay.SomeDayID != 2
and
   SomeDay.SomeDayID != 1;
```